# c++ template seems to break access specifiers

Tags: c++, templates

The following code doesn't compile for obvious reasons, namely that Foo is trying to access a private member of Bar. However if you uncomment/comment the lines marked, making Foo a template, it does compile and outputs 42. What am I missing here? Why does this work? Seems to me it shouldn't.

Thanks for your help.

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar {
    private:
    static const int x = 42;
};

//template <int>   // uncomment me
struct Foo {
    static const int i = Bar::x;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::cout << Foo::i    << std::endl;   // comment me
    //std::cout << Foo<0>::i << std::endl;   // uncomment me
}
```

Comment: Compiler bug, I'd guess.  Mine complains as it should.

Comment: `-1` from me for not mentioning the compiler in what might be a compiler bug.

Comment: sorry sbi, realised i should have done. Have put it as a comment to James' answer, its gcc 4.4.3

Comment: O, that's naughty, naughty from the developers of gcc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are seeing this behavior, it is a compiler bug.

Both Comeau Online and Visual C++ 2010 reject the code as invalid because `Bar::x` is inaccessible.  g++ 4.1.2 incorrectly accepts the invalid code (someone would need to test with a later version to see if it's been fixed; that's the only version I have on this laptop).

Comment: oh ok, thanks. I'm using gcc 4.4.3, should have mentioned that in the post

Comment: gcc 4.5.0 barks on the code as well. If I remember correctly clang doesn't do access checking yet.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like [GCC bug 40843](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40843). It is listed as UNCONFIRMED, but I can reproduce it on `g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3` as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Lets me know that it's known and stops me filing an unnecessary new bug report should I want to report my experience of it. Unfortunately I can't upvote because I'm not a registered user, but I would if I could and will when I am!

Comment: Good catch; I didn't find that one when I searched.  +1

Answer (score -4):

VisualStudio 2010 said "error C2248: 'Bar::x' [...]
As the plateform was not speciifed, I have assessed that the assumption is false almost on Windows VC9.