# Why is this template code allowed to violate C++'s private access specifier?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction

In the following code, which I found here:

http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

it appears to step right across C++'s private access specifier. It allows me to call private functions and read/write private data members.

Searching SO found this related issue which was a confirmed GCC compiler bug

[c++ template seems to break access specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128099/c-template-seems-to-break-access-specifiers)

So naturally I tried using that guy's test code. What was interesting is that my gcc 4.5 compiler indeed has that bug ( it accepts the code and prints the private info ) despite it being reported in gcc 4.3 and me using 4.5.

Anyway, I then went to the Comeau online compiler, which some of the responses to the thread said they tried. I confirmed Comeau *does not* accept the code from that question, but it *does* accept my code below.

So ultimately my question is, have I stumbled across a bug in GCC and Comeau's C++ compiler ? Does this compile with VC++ ? If it's not a bug, can someone explain how it works ? I get that it's able to declare a static member function pointer and point it to the private section, but how is it accomplishing this ?

Misc notes: Yes, I know that actually doing this is Very Very Bad. This will also work if you declare a member data ptr and allow you to read/write to private data. Some of the weird comments were from me trying to label it for understanding. I did not conjure up this code and I take no credit for it. I just found it on google. I may not have enough reputation points to reply to comments but I will read everything you say. Thanks for taking a look.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//--------------------------------------------
//
template<typename Tag>
struct result 
{
  /* export it ... */
  typedef typename Tag::type type;

  static type ptr;
};


// allocate space for the static member
template<typename Tag>
typename result<Tag>::type result<Tag>::ptr;

//--------------------------------------------

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type p>
struct rob : result<Tag> 
{
  /* fill it ... */
  struct filler 
  {
      filler() { result<Tag>::ptr = p; }
  };

  static filler filler_obj;
};

// allocate space for the static member
template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type p>
typename rob<Tag, p>::filler rob<Tag, p>::filler_obj;
//--------------------------------------------


struct A 
{
  private:

    void f() 
    {   
        cout << "hey, don't touch me I'm private!" << endl;
    }
};

struct Af  
{ 
    typedef void(A::*type)(); 
};
template class rob<Af, &A::f>;



int main()
{
    A a;
    (a.*result<Af>::ptr)();
}
```

~> ./a.out 
hey, don't touch me I'm private!

~> g++ --version
g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.5.0 20100604 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 160292]
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: MSVC2008 gives `error C2248: 'A::f' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'` at `template class rob<Af, &A::f>;`

Comment: I hope the code in my blog is fine.

Comment: @johannes, I hope you don't mind me using it. I was going to email you but I'm at work now. :)

Comment: sure, use and abuse it however you like

Comment: The access specifiers are **NOT** a security mechanism. They are there to provide you with warnings when you accidentally try and use the wrong methods **NOT** a mechanism to prevent abuse.

Comment: @Johannes, I think you may have answered this question indirectly in your post on Hidden Features of C++: "The key point is that the type of a member pointer is bound to the class that actually contains said member - not to the class that you specified when taking the address. This allows us to circumvent checking". If that is correct for this question, could you pls confirm ?

Answer (score 3):

As a Loki Astari said, public and private are just semantics for the compiler so it can give you warnings that you're not using your code the way you intended.

I don't play with method pointers much (if at all), so I haven't the patience to figure this out fully. But it's no different to doing a mixture of the following. That is to say, using pointer logic to point at whatever bit of memory you want and casting functions and methods and misusing them.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A 
{
  public:
    void g()
    {
      cout << "value of i is " << this->i << endl;
    }
    void setJ(int newJ) {
      j = newJ;
    }
    int i;
  private:
    int j;
};

int main() {

    A a;
    a.i = 5;
    a.setJ(10);

    // accessing private field j
    cout << "value of j is " << *((&a.i)+1) << endl;

    // creating a pointer to method g    
    void(A::*method)() = &A::g;

    // changing it to be a function pointer
    void(*function)(A*) = (void(*)(A*)) method;

    // using function pointer to call A::g  
    function(&a);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but your example is full of dubious casts, and does not even compile.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: @UncleBens Of course it's full of silly casts. I doubt anyone would see such code in a production environment. The point being that in C/C++ you can do some very strange things -- it's the only high-level language that I know of to retain the goto statement. As for me, the code compiled (with warnings) using g++. v4.5.2

Comment: The principle difference between Johannes' code and yours is that yours manipulates the pointer manually. so if you inserted more data before that point, you would have to recalculate the address. the other code will work even if you change the class around.

Comment: Yes, your answer is just showing that reinterpret_cast and pointer arithmetic allows all kinds of funny things (with undefined results). And even then `void(*function)(A*) = (void(*)(A*)) method;` just won't compile. But the question is about using perfectly valid (?) language constructs in order to circumvent the access restrictions. - This simply does not answer the question.